# Is it possible to whitelist an app from Google Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, samsung, android-11

It's actually not a big problem, but annoys my eyes when I usually intend to update some apps.

[image]

From the screenshot above, you see a name of an app and beside the name there's a warning sign and it said my device is at risk, though I believe that app is perfectly fine and there's nothing wrong with it.

This is when I tap the "See details":

[image]

There's also this setting:

[image]

I did turn on/off, and this is what happened if I turn it off:

[image]

Is it possible to remove that annoying notification by putting the app in a white list or something so that Play Protect wouldn't scan and would skip the app?

To simulate the goal I want, I backed up the app and uninstalled it:

[image]

And I want to be like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do this without uninstaling the app, but just whitelist the app from Play Protect?

**Edit :**

I just remembered that this would also happen when I *re-signature* an app by any tools that resign the original app from where it's originally obtained.

For instance, I downloaded an app from play store, back up the apk file and resign it this would happen and when installing it, there would be this notification:

[image]

But the app that I make an example above is the original app (I guess). Also, if I press 1) **OK**, Play Protect would do the job and the app wouldn't be able to be installed, but if I press 2) **Install anyway (unsafe)** (though actually there's no something wrong, so I think it's safe), the app would be successfully installed as normal.

This is the requested link from [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/471122ff957fdd30a31b554ca558818025b658ce997df8eadc7ce8f382dae02f/summary):

Comment: Can you upload the APK to https://virustotal.com and post the link to the result page?

Comment: @Robert I've edited the question as you have suggested and added the link.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to whitelist an app on Play Protect.